# How to create request using rest builder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I've forked and ran the [CRMRestBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder).

[image]

After running the solution I got this:

[image]

I then browsed to Xrm.RESTBuilder.htm, and got the following exception:

[image]

**How can I configure this to work with my environment? What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 5):

Install the managed solution into your CRM org and there will be a button on top of the Solutions page to launch - everything runs inside CRM.
https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/releases

https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder/wiki